# UITableView: Incorrect appearance of cell accessory view in edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview

My iOS app uses a UITableViewController to show a table view. The built-in edit button to switch to edit mode. Some of the cells need to show an accessory view, which is done by setting `cell.accessoryType = .detailButton`. At the same time `cell.editingAccessoryType = .none` is set on all the cells. The cells also show reordering, delete, and insert accessory views while in edit mode.

**Problem**

The problem is that when switching to edit mode, the accessory view stays behind on some cells, and moves to the top left corner of the cell. This seems to happen at random.

Below is the code which configures each cell:

```
private func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForTextFragment fragment: Fragment, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: basicCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BasicFragmentCell
    cell.contentTextField.text = fragment.value
    cell.showsReorderControl = true

    switch fragment.type {
    case .phoneNumber, .email:
        cell.accessoryType = .detailButton

    default:
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
    cell.editingAccessoryType = .none

    return cell
}
```

The full source is on GitHub: https://github.com/lukevanin/OCRAI

**Edit mode**

[image: Incorrect positioning of accessory view]

**Non-edit mode**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use a standard `UIViewController` with an embedded `UITableView`, instead of using a `UITableViewController`.

For editing to work correctly, the editing mode needs to be set explicitly on the `UITableView` when the editing state changes on the `UIViewController`, e.g.

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
}
```